# Is there anything wrong with this jquery function? Works in FF, Safari, but IE Dies

Tags: jquery, qtip

I'm using the qTip plugin for jQuery. Using the following function it cycles through each of the a tags with a rel attribute and applies the qtip function to each link. Works a treat in Firefox and Safari and is supposed to work in IE.

```
$('a[rel]').each(function () {
  var $link = $(this);
  $link.qtip({ 
      content: {
    url: '/tooltip.php',
    data: { tipKey: $link.attr('rel') },
    method: 'post'
      },
      style: { 
              border: { width: 9, radius: 9, color: '#C1AD06' },
        tip: { 
            corner: 'topLeft',
            size: {
                x: 55, 
                y : 34 
        }
    },
        width: { min:   393 },
        background: '#CBCB07',


      }
  });
});
```

Problem is, in IE7 it seems to break my javascript e.g all my other js functions.

I'm not sure how I go about debugging this... if I remove the above from my javascript file everything works fine.

I should mention that only a tags with rel attributes are related to tooltipping and nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of this comma:

```
background: '#CBCB07',
```

IE doesn't accept commas after the last item in an object. See [Last Comma in Object/Array Issue in IE](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ie/array_comma_problem.php).